# How to properly align partitions?

Tags: partition, fdisk, parted

I'm trying to understand what are the rules for creating correctly aligned partitions.

For the moment I'm playing with `parted` on a virtual machine, but I'm planning to move to a real hard disk when I feel more confident. I bought my laptop in 2008 so it doesn't have 4 KiB sectors, but 512 B ones. I'm going to use the EXT4 filesystem with 4 KiB blocks, so I suppose I need to align to 4 KiB anyway. As far as I know, sectors are numbered from zero and the first one is reserved for the MBR. So I conclude that I need to leave 7 sectors unused (4096 B / 512 B - 512 B) after the MBR, and the first partition could start at sector 8. The end of this partition could be any sector number that is one less than a number divisible by 8. For example 15, for an extremely small partition with just one EXT4 block.

The problem is that `parted` says me that "The resulting partition is not properly aligned for best performance", but doesn't tell me what's wrong exactly. If I try to use `fdisk` instead, I cannot even use a sector less than 2048 (1 MiB) for the start of the first partition. I searched for a rationale behind this, but I found nothing.

In the future I could be interested in partitioning rules that also take in consideration LVM, RAID and encryption, but this is not really important for the moment. I need to understand the basics first.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I asked on the util-linux mailing list (the ''fdisk'' program belongs to the util-linux package). You can read the whole thread [here](http://thread.gmane.org/gmane.linux.utilities.util-linux-ng/6508). Let me quote the relevant portions.

Kay Sievers said:

> It's a de-facto standard, which Windows does too. The first megabyte is reserved here for a boot loader or any other management data that could be needed for a disk or box to boot from.

Karel Zak said:

> The real reason is that 1MiB is ideal offset to keep partitions aligned on almost all random hardware. This offset is compatible with 512-byte, 4096-byte sector devices, many raid devices as well as old broken WD disks where physical sector size has been incorrectly reported. You can use dd(1) to move your PT + data to another device without care about physical device topology (I/O limits), etc.
>
> It's also important to keep your partition sizes aligned to MiB -- this is for example default in fdisk if you specify the size in +{M,G} convention.